# Vuejs - How to create or use a "compilation id"?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA who need to automatically detect if she need to be updated by the user.

When I compile ("npm run production") I would like generate an ID or any hash and then write it in a table or a file.

It is possible ?

NB : After that on my client side, I will check (by api call) if a new version exists by comparing the hash or id version.

Thanks

Comment: can you mention a use case. What exactly you want to achieve and why do you wan'a do  it.

Comment: It's a classic frontend/backend problem in SPA (Single Page Application).
The client app is rarely updated. Si I need to check if client and serve had same version. A manual solution it's not interesting. I need a perfect solution. Each time I run "npm run production" package.json version attribute++ and the window.app_version = process.env.APP_VERSION something like that